# Can't add Sherlock library to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I can't create project from ScerlockActionBar library, because it's inactive for some reason:

[image]

Any ideas - why it's happens? I've created projects from source before and everything was ok, but not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means it's already been added. Just look for it in eclipse.

Comment: Now I see, there was another library named exactly like that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

project.properties file is missing.